# Findind product key for installed Sharepoint 2007 server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint 2007 Server... is there a way to find the product key that was used to install this in the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help: [How To Recover Your SharePoint 2007 Product ID](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/johnson_bert/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=10)